# Move Global.asax to Class Library asp.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, global-asax

I would like to have only my \Views \Content \Scripts etc. only in my Project.Web in asp.NET MVC3.  I have moved everything but I am having trouble with the Global.asax.  I am getting a 404 Error when browsing.  I am wanting a structure like

```
Project
-Controllers
-Models
-Services
-Repositories
Global.asax
Global.asax.cs

Project.Web
-Content
-Scripts
-Views
```

Possible?

Comment: Darin is correct, think of Global.asax as a content file (like an aspx or html page). The content page inherits from a class which is a codebehind in the default template but can be moved to a library.

Comment: Yes, Darin is correct, works like a charm!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `Global.asax` must be located in your web tier. The `Global.asax.cs` could be in a class library.